# How to close browser tab with alert message in c#

Tags: c#

I have been trying with below code its getting execute but messagebox not displaying and tab also not getting close.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Messagebox", "alert('Record Deleted successfully.Note: This tab is now getting close');", true);
```

so i just remove the 'alert' code from above code then its getting execute and getting close the tab. But I also want to display notification message box so how?

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Messagebox", "window.close();", true);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3888938/952310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try from javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Showalert() {
        alert('Call JavaScript function from codebehind');
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

and then call it from your codebehind side werever you want.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "Showalert();", true);
```

hopw this will help you.
thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Just combine both calls into one, and call the one after the other:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Messagebox", "alert('Record Deleted successfully.Note: This tab is now getting close');window.close();", true);
```

Comment: Not sure of what you're asking but: the 2 javascript pieces are glued together.

Comment: @MatteoSp cant execute two scripts at a time.

Comment: can you clarify "cant execute two scripts at a time"?

Answer (score 0):

Write like this..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"showalert","alert('Only alert Message');",true);
```

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Messagebox", "alert('Record Deleted successfully.Note: This tab is now getting close');", true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Messagebox", "window.close();", true);